# How control DAG concurrency in airflow

Tags: python, airflow

I use airflow v1.7.1.3

I have two DAG, dag_a and dag_b.
I set up 10 dag_a tasks at one time, which theoretically should be execution one by one. In reality, the 10 dag_a tasks are executed in parallel.
The concurrency parameter doesn't work. Can anyone tell me why?

Here's the pseudocode：

in dag_a.py

```
dag = DAG('dag_a',
            start_date=datetime.now(),
            default_args=default_args,
            schedule_interval=None,
            concurrency=1,
            max_active_runs=1)
```

in dag_b.py

```
from fabric.api import local

dag = DAG('dag_b',
            start_date=datetime.now(),
            default_args=default_args,
            schedule_interval='0 22 */1 * *',
            concurrency=1,
            max_active_runs=1)


def trigger_dag_a(**context):

    dag_list = []
    for rec in rang(1,10):
        time.sleep(2)
        cmd = "airflow trigger_dag dag_a"

        log.info("cmd:%s"%cmd)
        msg = local(cmd)    #"local" is function in fabric
        log.info(msg)


trigger_dag_a_proc = PythonOperator(python_callable=trigger_dag_a,
                          provide_context=True,
                          task_id='trigger_dag_a_proc',
                          dag=dag)
```

Answer (score 9):

You can limit your task instances by specifying a pool.

1. Create a pool in the UI:

[image: Pool]

2.Then setup your dags to use this pool:

```
        default_args = {
                    'email_on_failure': False,
                    'email_on_retry': False,
                    'start_date': datetime(2017, 12, 16),
                    'pool': 'my_pool'
                }

        dag = DAG(
            dag_id='foo',
            schedule_interval='@daily',
            default_args=default_args,
        )
```

Comment: If multiple dags are assigned to the same pool, do they share the slots? Or does each dag get the number of slots specified by the pool (ie: in the above example each dag gets 10 slots)?

Comment: @user3776598 they will share the pool slots

Comment: there is a "pool" argument in DAG's default args, but an operator also has a "pool" argument, if i set them differently, which one takes precedence?

Comment: Thanks @x97Core.  This worked for me but task_concurency/max_active_tis_per_dag did not.  I am using dynamic tasks, so task concurrency likely applies to each dynamic task since they all have different task ids.

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK, external dag triggers do not respect the concurrency/max_active_runs parameters of the DAGs. This also applies to backfills.

Only dag runs scheduled by the scheduler respect these parameters.

Comment: But I found that their external trigger was also scheduled for the scheduler.
So for dag_a, first I'm going to trigger it in a running state, and then I'm going to submit a trigger again, and this new task is going to do the pool wait.

Comment: I also encounter this situation and scheduled dag runs didn't respect the concurrency/max_active_runs parameters. Don't know why.. Had to set a pool as @x97Core showed.